# Share dataset between mongodb instances - looking for design

Tags: mongodb, containers, amazon-ecs

Here I don't have code, as I'm looking for architectural / design approaches and their pros / cons.

**Description**

I'm going to deploy AWS ECS tasks and each tasks runs a MongoBD container and our product container. These are running on same EC2 instance. By this way, I want to optimize the memory utilization, performance and gain some cost optimization.

**The problem**

If this system is going to scale up, my understanding is that multiple tasks will start and each of them need a file set for MongoDB - which in my case should contain the same data and must keep in sync. On the other hand, when the service scale down (event stopped completely), at least one instance must be preserved

Can anybody help me what would be the right design approach?

I already considered:

- AWS EBS Volume mounted on the EC2

  - seems no real support to mount same volume to multiple instance
  - I'm not sure if multiple mongodb can work on same set of files
- ASW EFS:

  - the shared mounting would be solved here
  - multiple mongodb instance targets same set of files
- MongoDB sharding:

  - how can I on-the-flight extend the sharding configuration with the newly deployed tasks
- Single, dedicated mongodb service

  - that's what I wanted to avoid, as due to the rear peak loads, I have to run large EC2 instance all over the time

Comment: "...and each of them need a file set for MongoDB - which in my case should contain the same data and must keep in sync. " That is not the principle of sharding. When you have a sharded cluster then the data is distributed over the shards, i.e. each shard has different data and they are not synced.